# Concepts for more interesting introductions in papers

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, introduction

What are the key concepts for writing introductory text more interesting to the reader?

An example:

> The Deutsche Bahn AG is the company with the most energy consumption
>   in Germany. It has therefore a interest in efficient usage of it.

compared to

> As one of Germany's biggest energy consumers, the Deutsche Bahn AG is
>   interested in efficient energy usage.

As opening sentence of the Introduction. Both contain the same information, but to me the second sounds much more interesting.

Comment: Either way you're in trouble if you don't have correct syntax and grammar. German is a very different language. Who is your audience? What is its purpose? An introduction can be one sentence or several pages. What is the main substance that you're introducing?

Comment: Surely this either belongs on a language-specific SE site, or is too subjective in nature? What sounds "much more interesting" to one is not likely to be rule-based.

Answer (score 1):

1) Both of the examples you provide contain phrases that have converted verbs into noun phrases. Revert the phrases back into their verb form. For example:

Before: The Deutsche Bahn AG is the company with the most energy consumption in Germany.

After: Deutsche Bahn AG consumes more energy than any other company in Germany.

2) Illustrate the enormity of the problem. Use a number, a comparison and/or an analogy to make the issue real and tangible to your audience. For example:

A quantity: In 2014, its rail, bus, trucking, and airfreight operations consumed the 15 Million Gigajoules, which is equivalent to N tonnes of oil.

A comparison: This is more than the next 10 largest consumers of energy in Germany combined, including Mercedes-Benz, Siemens, etc.

If you are [trying to persuade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_of_persuasion), appeal to your audience's logic, emotions, and morality (logos, pathos,  ethos).